# Rotation after reaching given point

Tags: html, css, css-animations

i want to rotate my image/ or element right after it reached to its location given in `keframe` breakpoints.
rotation and animation are being applied together.
Here is `HTML`

```
<body>
<div class="container">

    <div class="box"></div>

</div>
```

and here is the CSS.

```
.container {
    background-color: lightgray;
    height: 600px;
    width: 800px;
    margin: auto;
 }

.box {
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    // background-image: url("car.png");
    background-size:100px 100px;
    position: relative;
    top:40px; left: 620px;
    animation: Glider infinite 5s ease-in-out;
 }

@keyframes Glider {
    0% {
        top:40px; left:620px;        
    }
    25% {
        top:40px; left: 80px;
        transform: rotate(-90deg);
    }
    50%{
        top:400px; left: 80px;
        transform: rotate(-180deg);
    }
    75%{
        top:400px; left: 620px;
        transform: rotate(-270deg);
    }
    100%{
        top:40px; left: 620px;
        transform: rotate(-360deg);
   }
}
```

What i wanted to do is move image to `top:40px; left: 80px;` then stay `rotate(-90deg)` , after rotation applied move to next point. 
Want this to happen on every turning point.
LINK:  https://output.jsbin.com/hiyamirera/1
WHAT AM I MISSING?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try something like this. The idea is to force the same value of rotation in the frames so it won't rotate while translating and you change the rotation between 2 close frames.

```css
.container {
  background-color: lightgray;
  height: 600px;
  width: 800px;
  margin: auto;
}

.box {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background: red;
  position: relative;
  top: 40px;
  left: 620px;
  animation: Glider infinite 5s ease-in-out;
}

@keyframes Glider {
  0% {
    top: 40px;
    left: 620px;
    transform: rotate(0);
  }
  25% {
    top: 40px;
    left: 80px;
    transform: rotate(0);
  }
  28% {
    transform: rotate(-90deg);
  }
  50% {
    top: 400px;
    left: 80px;
    transform: rotate(-90deg);
  }
  53% {
    transform: rotate(-180deg);
  }
  75% {
    top: 400px;
    left: 620px;
    transform: rotate(-180deg);
  }
  78% {
    transform: rotate(-270deg);
  }
  97% {
    top: 40px;
    left: 620px;
    transform: rotate(-270deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(-360deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

  <div class="box"></div>

</div>
```

Comment: Thank You Man!  i try within close frames too but the idea of stopping rotation between translating image didnt hit me!